Real analysis question about function measurablity
If we know that function f(x,y) defined on R2 is measurable.When we fixed x,the function h(y)=f(x,y) is measurable?I don’t how to prove this.Could you help me? Thanks for advanced!

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.
